# google play store: how to cancel a "ready to publish" version

Tags: android, google-play

I have 2 versions of my app ready to publish, but one of them is set as a full rollout and i need a way to delete it or change the rollout percentage.

These are the steps of how I got to this state:

1. all of my users had v1 of my app
2. I sent v2 for review but forgot to set the staged rollout percentage
3. I stopped the review
4. uploaded v3 with some fixes and a 30% rollout. At this point, both versions were shown as ready for review.
5. I was not able to delete v2 so I sent both for review.
6. Both were approved

I have "managed publishing" on so both versions are "ready to publish".

I need to delete v2.

I'm not sure what will happen if i click publish. Either google will only look at v3 and leave me with a 70% install base on v1 and 30% on v3, or they will rollout both and I'll have 70% v2 and 30% v3

I've read other similar questions here and on other sites, but none are in a staged rollout case

when i canceled v2's (but after uploading v3) i looked everywhere for a "delete version button" but couldn't find it.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: When Google added "Managed publishing" feature on top of existing system, the whole system start working badly. Everything is fine while you keep Managed Publishing off, but as soon as you turn it on, a bunch of problems arise. One is that you can't change rollout from full rollout to staged once approved by Google. Others you already mentioned. BTW, what the terrible choice of words - it should not called Managed Publishing ON, but all the way around - it should be Automatic Publishing OFF. The way how they called it is confusing.